# Has this paper used weighted KNN or not?

Tags: classification, k-nn

Please tell me if you see this paper in the link below has used weighted KNN? because they have used weights as the training and testing samples and no formula written. They don't explain the procedure of their KNN. Have they used Euclidean distance for that?

Paper link: https://we.tl/t-H0vKm0g9iD

Comment: Can you please provide a proper DOI number or link to a journal site for the paper

Comment: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s12652-018-0934-9

Answer (score 0):

The reference for their KNN algorithm is [Zhang et al. 2017](https://scholar.google.com/scholar_lookup?title=Learning%20k%20for%20kNN&author=S.%20Zhang&author=X.%20Li&author=M.%20Zong&author=X.%20Zhu&author=D.%20Cheng&journal=Classif%20ACM%20Trans%20Intell%20Syst%20Technol&volume=8&pages=43&publication_year=2017), furthermore in their paper they reference that they are using the standard settings for the toolkit (k = 5 etc). In my understanding the weighting they are doing is extracting features out of the text not within the actual KNN algorithm. If their KNN algorithim was weighted then the paper would have specified 'weighted KNN'

Comment: Thank you so much, your answer was so helpful. I still have some inquiry because I am a master student and every step should be justified in the thesis. if I wanted to use weighted KNN here, should I have to use the weights resulted from the features extraction? I how can I justify the difference between these Weights of feature extraction and the weights I get using the inverse/sum of inverses for the weighted KNN?